# change page numbering of the page that is Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I want change the place of the page number of the page that is Table of Contents to bottom side of paper. please help me.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I would guess, that is 'just' kicking out `\thispagestyle{empty}` out of `\tableofcontents` but without example, it's no real solution

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick and dirty method to remove `empty` page style from the `\tableofcontents` command by patching it out. It works with `book`, `scrbook` and most probably with many other classes based on them.

Since no further information is given, this is just a first step on the road to... page numbers on the bottom of the ToC page

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}{}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Get this thing off the list :-)